# How can I check if a Tomcat7 user instance is running?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I started a Tomcat7 user instance with `tomcat7-instance/bin/startup.sh`, but how can I chek if that instance is running or not? Of course, an easier way than with `ps | grep`.

I know that to check the service status you can use `service tomcat7 status`, but this is an user instance.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 and 13.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed from repositories then `service tomcat7 status` should work. Or `/etc/init.d/tomcat7 status`:

My output from running either of the above commands is below:

`Tomcat servlet engine is running with pid 14416.`

The way that debian checks is by the below command:

`start-stop-daemon --test --start --pidfile /var/run/tomcat7.pid --user tomcat7 --exec /usr/bin/java >/dev/null 2>&1; echo $?`

If the value returned is anything but 0 then tomcat is running.

Comment: Is your OS Redhat/Centos? Do you use 3rd party repo, because with official Redhat repo there is no tomcat7 package

Comment: The problem is that I want to check this for a tomcat user instance not the service itself.

Comment: When I try `sudo service tomcat8 status` I get `..        [OK]` as a response...what's happening? I am running an Amazon Linux AMI

Comment: I am using sysvinit, I got whats going on, the script has a bug, it calls `success` which prints [  OK  ] in the same line as the console. It's supposed to have an echo after the success command to change lines and print the green OK after some text